# memory allication problems c

Tags: c, memory

:)

I've got a really annoying problem while trying to alloc some memory for my matrix. The code just doesnt bother to work. It always exits with minus one. :(
code is down below...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mx{
    int row1;
    int col1;
    double* m1;
    } mx_t;

void mallocmatrix(mx_t* mat1){
    mat1->m1 = malloc(mat1->row1 * mat1->col1 * sizeof(double));
    if(mat1->m1 == 0){
        printf("theres something wrong:( \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mx_t mat1;

    mat1.row1 = argv[2]; mat1.col1 = argv[3];

    mallocmatrix(&mat1);

    free(mat1.m1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using argv wrong. Read about command line arguments.

Comment: `argv` is an array of *strings*. If your compiler isn't giving you warnings already, then enable more warnings and treat them as errors.

Answer (score -1):

1. The line

`mat1->m1 = malloc(mat1->row1 * mat1->col1 * sizeof(double));`

need change to

`mat1->m1 = malloc(sizeof(double));`

2. The line

`mat1.row1 = argv[2]; mat1.col1 = argv[3];`

need change to

`mat1.row1 = atoi(argv[2]); mat1.col1 = atoi(argv[3]);`

The type of `mat1.row` is `int`, the type of `argv[1]` is `char*`

Comment: How `mat1->m1 = malloc(sizeof(double));` will make a Matrix?

Comment: The `atoi` part is correct. Just remove this `malloc` nonsense.

Comment: And also note that the first argument is `[1]` and second is `[2]`

Comment: @kiranBiradar The type of `m1` is `double*`.

Comment: But OP needs an array. For your case why do you need a pointer if it is going to point only one double? Just  `double m1;` should be sufficient.

Comment: @kiranBiradar The question should ask László Fera , not me.

Comment: thanks for the fast answers guys :) 
i missed to convert the arguments into integers :( 
i forgot it though i have put it in my previous codes /sigh